# text that pops up when a button is clicked then fades out html

Tags: html

So I have a button and a text I want to show the text when the button is pressed then wait 2s and the text will fade out how can I do that? I tried making a function that sets the opacity to 1 and then play an animtion that will set the opacity to 0 but it will glitch so i don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far. See [ask].

Comment: ok thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this by using Javascript to manipulate the CSS of the text.

### 1. Using Only Opacity and JavaScript (*And you care about display being set to none*)

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let text = document.getElementById("text");
  text.classList.remove("hide");
  setTimeout(function () {
    text.classList.add("fade-in");
    setTimeout(function () {
      text.classList.remove("fade-in");
      setTimeout(function () {
        text.classList.add("hide");
      }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

#text.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}


#text.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="text" class="hide">I am a text that fades</p>
<button id="button">Fade Text</button>
```

Use this if you absolutely care about the element truly leaving the view (display being set to none). Because display cannot be animated, it uses a chain of timeouts to fade the element after the display has been completely changed.

### 2. Using Opacity and JavaScript without display being set to none

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let text = document.getElementById("text");
  text.classList.add("fade-in");
  setTimeout(function () {
    text.classList.remove("fade-in");
  }, 3000); // Set time out to three seconds to account for the second the element fades in
});
```

```css
#text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

#text.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">I am a text that fades</p>
<button id="button">Fade Text</button>
```

This creates a smoother animation but as you can see, the element doesn't truly leave the DOM, it has it's space from before since we just made it transparent.

### 3. Using Only JavaScript, No CSS (*And you care about display set to none*)

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let text = document.getElementById("text");
// Initialize text display & opacity to none and zero respectively
text.style.display = "none"
text.style.opacity = 0
let isClickable = true
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  // Set the display to block so we can animate it
  text.style.display = "block";
  text.style.opacity = 0;
  let i = 0;
  // Based on the duration set in the data-attribute, calculate each fraction of the duration we need to animate the opacity by 1% to achieve a smooth transition
  let interval = (parseInt(text.dataset.duration) * 1000) / 100;
  if(isClickable) {
    isClickable = false
    let id = setInterval(function () {
    // Add 1% opacity at each interval
    i += 0.01;
    // Round the figure down to 2 decimal places because JavaScript addition adds trailing zeros
    text.style.opacity = i.toFixed(2);
    // When we get to one kill the current interval and fire a timeout for the 2 second duration specified in the question
    if (i >= 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
      setTimeout(function () {
        // Run similar interval to fade out element
        let idd = setInterval(function () {
          i -= 0.01;
          text.style.opacity = i.toFixed(2);
          if (i <= 0) {
            clearInterval(idd);
            // Set display back to none
            text.style.display = "none";
            isClickable = true;
          }
        }, interval);
      }, 2000); // wait for 2 seconds
    }
  }, interval);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<p id="text" data-duration="2">I am a text that fades</p>
<!-- data-duration is how long the animation should last in seconds -->
<button id="button">Fade Text</button>
```

### 4. Finally, use jQuery

```js
$('#text').hide()
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#text').fadeIn()
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#text').fadeOut()
  }, 3000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">I am a text that fades</p>
<button id="button">Fade Text</button>
```

Comment: nvm i fixed it ty

Answer (score 2):

try something like this to the text but only add the class .text on the button click:

```
.text {
    animation: text 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes text {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    } 25% {
        opacity: 1;
    } 75% {
        opacity: 1;
    } 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: it only runs once like when i click the button again it wont do anything

Comment: in the javascript add a text.onAnimationEnd to remove the class and then when you add it again it should restart the animation

Comment: k i dont need it anymore coz i found the solution but thanks anyway